# PyQt5 QtWebEngine font error

Tags: pyqt5, qtwebengine

I tried to use PyQt 5 to show some local website, but the program failed.
Here is the log info:

```
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
2016-11-09 22:23:01.126 QtWebEngineProcess[48297:7328996] XType: failed to connect - Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.fonts was invalidated.}
2016-11-09 22:23:01.126 QtWebEngineProcess[48297:7328996] Font server protocol version mismatch (expected:5 got:0), falling back to local fonts
2016-11-09 22:23:01.126 QtWebEngineProcess[48297:7328996] XType: unable to make a connection to the font daemon!
2016-11-09 22:23:01.126 QtWebEngineProcess[48297:7328996] registering /System/Library/Fonts/*, /System/Library/Fonts/Base/*, and /Library/Fonts/* locally
```

I guess maybe this is because I use it on Mac, and I don't know to solve this problem, could you give me some suggestion about how to solve this font problem? Thanks

Comment: I really hope you get an answer for that. I'm having this problem and many others, since I'm currently developing to "Linux, Windows, Mac, Raspberry". If I do get some answer I gotta help you :D

Comment: @Y.Melo Thanks, and if I can find out how to solve this I'll tell you :D